# can't get right when dealing with uppercasing string

Tags: string, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def to_weird_case(string):
    lines = string.split()
    new_word = ''
    new_line = ''
    for word in lines:
        for item in word:
            if word.index(item) %2 ==0:
                item = item.upper()
                new_word += item
            else:
                new_word += item
        new_line = new_word +' '
    return new_line
print to_weird_case('what do you mean')
```

I want to get `WhAt Do YoU MeAn`, instead I got `WhAtDoYoUMeAn`. I already add the line `new_line = new_word +' '`. where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you overwrite `new_line` with every iteration. Second, `new_word` is getting longer because you never "clear" it. Third, you add space   to the end of the entire `new_line` and not after every new word (because of *Second*).

*See comments*

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    lines = string.split()
    new_line = ''
    for word in lines:
        new_word = '' # start new word from an empty string
        for item in word:
            if word.index(item) %2 ==0:
                item = item.upper()
                new_word += item
            else:
                new_word += item
        print new_word
        new_line = new_line + new_word + " " # add new word to the existing new line 
    return new_line
```

Comment: It worked! I must have been confused where to put `new_line`.

Comment: But what if i want to leave out the last space. it will print something like `' WhAt Do YoU MeAn  '`, which has an extra space at the end of the sentence.

Comment: You can remove the last space before 'return'.  Not a beautiful solution though :)

Comment: There is another problem though. When I was testing `this is a test`, I found that there are two "t" in "test". As a result, `index` finds the index of the last "t" to be `0` and uppercasing it.

Comment: Try ti uppercase every second letter using 'range(0,len(word),2)' (with step 2).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that your code did not reset the value of `new_word` and you overwrote the `new_line` within the loop, but I'd like to share a next to one-liner solution with a regex:

```
import re
def to_weird_case(string):
    return re.sub(r'(\S)(\S?)', lambda m: "{0}{1}".format(m.group(1).upper(), m.group(2)), string);
print to_weird_case('what do you mean')
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QIzRyE)

The `(\S)(\S?)` regex captures a non-whitespace into Group 1 and one or zero non-whitespaces into Group 2, and then, inside the `re.sub`, the Group 1 value is replaced with the uppercased counterpart.

Look at how [`(\S)(\S?)`](https://regex101.com/r/yV9rJ7/1) matches your `what do you mean`:

- `wh` is matches and `w` is in Group 1 and `h` is in Group 2 ([image]). The match is passed as `m` to the lambda expression, and Group 1 is modified, and Group 2 is just passed as is.
- The next match contains `at`, and the same thing happens with groups
- Next, the space is not matched since `\S` matches any character but a whitespace.
- `do` is matched, the same things happens as described above
- space, `yo` are matched and handled as described above
- `u` + *empty space* are matched next because the second `\S` has a `?` quantifier that matches one or zero occurrences of the pattern it modifies. Thus, the first char is uppercased and the second empty string is used as is.
- Then the rest is processed in a similar way.

Comment: Yeah, it is much simpler. It's long way for me to go.